# mvc routing examples for categories and sub-categories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

i have a static website (no database) and am having difficulty understanding how to setup routes for sub-categories. for example, i can do the following where the category is the controller and the make is the action:

- cars/toyota
- cars/bwm

but when i add another level i don't know how to setup the route

- cars/toyota/camry
- cars/toyota/corolla
- cars/toyota/celica

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with year/make/model

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",
   "{controller}/{year}/{make}/{model}"
   new
   {
       controller = "car", 
       action = "search",
       year = DateTime.Today.Year,
       model = "all",
       make = Url.OptionalParameter
   }
);
```

(you might want a constraint on the year to force it to be a reasonable value?)

with a controller like

```
public class CarController 
{

    public ActionResult Search( int year, string make, string model )
    {
         // handle model "all" and empty "make" specially
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok with a route looking like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "CarsRoute",
   "cars/{make}/{model}",
   new { 
      controller = "Cars", 
      action = "Display", 
      make = UrlParameter.Optional, 
      model = UrlParameter.Optional 
   });
```

This would map to an action method with the signature:

```
public ActionResult Display(string make, string model)
```

Where both `make` and `model` can be null. You can then perform your actions.

Comment: MVC3 doesn't handle routes with multiple optional parameters well, one of the two ought to have a default. This will help if the OP uses or upgrades to MVC3.  The problem comes in when you attempt to use this to generate a route; it fails.

Comment: Yeah, the make could well have a default value.